# Проблема с построением меню

Tags: php

У меня сейчас такой код:

```
<? if ($menu): ?>                    
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="http://<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>"> SITE</a></li>
        <?foreach($menu as $item):
            if($item['parent'] == 0):?>
                <li><a class="parentItem" href="/p/<?=$item['url'];?>"> <?=$item['name'];?></a>

        </li>

        <? endif;
        endforeach; ?>

    </ul> 
    <ul class="nav right">
        <li><a><i class="icon-profile"></i> <?=$user['first_name']." ".$user['last_name'];?></a></li>
        <? if($user['level'] == 1):?>
        <li><a href="/admin">Администрирование</a></li>
        <? endif;?>
        <li><a href="/logout"><i class="icon-signout"></i> Выход</a></li>

    </ul>
<? endif; ?>
```

Условие: есть 1 массив, где лежат все пункты меню, как основные, так и под меню. Для определения есть специальная ячейка - parent. Собственно, я достал все пункты, где нет родителя (parent = 0), осталось к ним достать под меню.
Как это сделать?
Возможно ли как-нибудь форматировать массив? Пытался сделать через функцию, но получилось плохо, т.к. массивы не чистятся и везде выдает одно и тоже значение.

Answer (score 1):

В google по запросу типа "[Построение дерева иерархии](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Построение+дерева+иерархии)" - информации море, поэтому не вижу смысла повторяться тут. И лучше бы вы не показывали свой код, за который можно минусов нахватать, что собака блох, а показали тот самый массив. В общем, [рекурсия](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+php) вам в помощь.